# Short for() loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var navLinkA = document.getElementsByClassName('navLinkA');

for(i = 0 ; i < navLinkA.lentgh ; i++) {
    navLinkA.item(i).addEventListener('click',function(){
        alert('asdf');
        }
    );
}
```

Above is the code. Defining variable was fine. 
Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: Use resources available to you, like the console, in a lot of circumstances it will give you information on where you went wrong.

Comment: yes, that was my misstake. I fixed it. and trying to use consol, but it's not working until now. I remember other similar code used one more variable 'len'.. that code didn't use .length directly.

Comment: baejusik, rather than editing an already closed solved question turning it into a totally different question, it's better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a start, the word is spelt `length`, not `lentgh`.

Depending on the environment, it may simply stop on an error like that, or it may give you an indication (which may include an indication you need to go looking for in a console window).

Comment: would you read the question again? typing problem is not only thing... the real problem is exist.